# Confused about apache if else

Tags: apache, if-statement, configuration, location

I'm trying to use apache IF ELSE inside a Location or Directory block in my apache2.conf to restrict access to all files and directories in all virtual hosts in once place.

Only users in US and Canada should be allowed access to anything. I have the MaxMind GeoIP2 module and databases installed, and that correctly sets the environment variables. But, I must be misunderstanding how the SetEnvIf or If works. Or maybe I don't have access to environment variables here?

Anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
<IfModule mod_maxminddb.c>
  MaxMindDBEnable On
  MaxMindDBFile COUNTRY_DB /var/lib/GeoIP/GeoIP2-Country.mmdb
  MaxMindDBFile CITY_DB    /var/lib/GeoIP/GeoLite2-City.mmdb
  MaxMindDBEnv COUNTRY_CODE COUNTRY_DB/country/iso_code
  MaxMindDBEnv COUNTRY_NAME CITY_DB/country/names/en
  MaxMindDBEnv CITY_NAME CITY_DB/city/names/en
  MaxMindDBEnv REGION_CODE  CITY_DB/subdivisions/0/iso_code
</IfModule>

<Location />
  SetEnvIf COUNTRY_CODE ^(US|CA) AllowCountry
  <If "-T env('AllowCountry')">
    Require all granted
  </If>
  <Else>
    Require all denied
  </Else>
</Location>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this…

```
SetEnvIf COUNTRY_CODE ^(US|CA) AllowCountry=1

<If "reqenv('AllowCountry') == '1'">
```

Or why not skip the SetEnvIf and just do…

```
<If "reqenv('COUNTRY_CODE') =~ /^(US|CA)/">
```

Untested. Happy to update if it needs tweaking. Hopefully you get the idea - set the env var *to* something and check it explicitly or just check the COUNTRY_CODE env var directly in the condition.

Also [this](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#functions) might be worth noting…

> Environment variable ordering
> When environment variables are looked up within an  condition, it's important to consider how extremely early in request processing that this resolution occurs. As a guideline, any directive defined outside of virtual host context (directory, location, htaccess) is not likely to have yet had a chance to execute. SetEnvIf in virtual host scope is one directive that runs prior to this resolution
>
> When reqenv is used outside of , the resolution will generally occur later, but the exact timing depends on the directive the expression has been used within.

Hope that helps.